# @dnd kit list sorting not working properly when parent div has transform:scale() css

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, drag-and-drop, dnd-kit

@dnd-kit list sorting not working properly when parent div has transform:scale() css.

In one of my project there is one feature for zoom In/Out. And That I am managing with transform:scale(). But now in the child component I am using @dnd-kit sortable library to sort my blocks. but because of that transform:scale() css sorting is not working properly like cursor and block are not moving aligned.

here is my demo link: [https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dndkit-sorting-4gxnz7.](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dndkit-sorting-4gxnz7)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [doc method](https://docs.dndkit.com/api-documentation/draggable#transforms) didn't work for me.

The only way I found was this:

```
  const style = {
    transform: CSS.Translate.toString({
      x: (transform?.x * 10) / 7,
      y: (transform?.y * 10) / 7,
    }),
    transition,
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

you should recalculate your sortable item x, y transform values with parents scale value.

kinda like this,

```
   const style = {
        transform: CSS.Translate.toString({
          x: transform?.x / SCALE_VALUE,
          y: transform?.y / SCALE_VALUE,
        }),
        transition,
      };
```

Sortable Item like,

```
 <div ref={setNodeRef} style={style}>
     {children}
 </div>
```

Comment: Very similar answer to another answer given.